# Can't make apache beam write outputs to bigquery when using DataflowRunner

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to understand why this pipeline writes no output to `BigQuery`.
What I'm trying to achieve is to calculate the USD index for the last 10 years, starting from different currency pairs observations.

All the data is in `BigQuery` and I need to organize it and sort it in a chronollogical way (if there is a better way to achieve this, I'm glad to read it because I think this might not be the optimal way to do this).

The idea behing the class `Currencies()` is to start grouping (and keep) the last observation of a currency pair (eg: EURUSD), update all currency pair values as they "arrive", sort them chronologically and finally get the open, high, low and close value of the USD index for that day.

This code works in my jupyter notebook and in cloud shell using `DirectRunner`, but when I use `DataflowRunner` it does not write any output. In order to see if I could figure it out, I tried to just create the data using `beam.Create()` and then write it to `BigQuery` (which it worked) and also just read something from `BQ` and write it on other table (also worked), so my best guess is that the problem is in the `beam.CombineGlobally` part, but I don't know what it is.

The code is as follows:

```
import logging
import collections
import apache_beam as beam

from datetime import datetime

SYMBOLS = ['usdjpy', 'usdcad', 'usdchf', 'eurusd', 'audusd', 'nzdusd', 'gbpusd']

TABLE_SCHEMA = "date:DATETIME,index:STRING,open:FLOAT,high:FLOAT,low:FLOAT,close:FLOAT"

class Currencies(beam.CombineFn):
    def create_accumulator(self):
        return {}
    
    def add_input(self,accumulator,inputs):
        logging.info(inputs)
        date,currency,bid = inputs.values()
        if '.' not in date:
            date = date+'.0'        
        date = datetime.strptime(date,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
        data = currency+':'+str(bid)
        accumulator[date] = [data]
        return accumulator
    
    def merge_accumulators(self,accumulators):
        merged = {}
        for accum in accumulators:
            ordered_data = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(accum.items()))
            prev_date = None
            for date,date_data in ordered_data.items():
                if date not in merged:
                    merged[date] = {}
                    if prev_date is None:
                        prev_date = date
                    else:
                        prev_data = merged[prev_date]
                        merged[date].update(prev_data)
                        prev_date = date

                for data in date_data:
                    currency,bid = data.split(':')
                    bid = float(bid)
                    currency = currency.lower()
                    merged[date].update({
                        currency:bid
                    })
        return merged
    
    def calculate_index_value(self,data):
        return data['usdjpy']*data['usdcad']*data['usdchf']/(data['eurusd']*data['audusd']*data['nzdusd']*data['gbpusd'])
    
    def extract_output(self,accumulator):
        ordered = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(accumulator.items()))
        index = {}
        for dt,currencies in ordered.items():
            if not all([symbol in currencies.keys() for symbol in SYMBOLS]):
                continue
            date = str(dt.date())
            index_value = self.calculate_index_value(currencies)
            if date not in index:
                index[date] = {
                    'date':date,
                    'index':'usd',
                    'open':index_value,
                    'high':index_value,
                    'low':index_value,
                    'close':index_value
                }
            else:
                max_value = max(index_value,index[date]['high'])
                min_value = min(index_value,index[date]['low'])
                close_value = index_value
                index[date].update({
                    'high':max_value,
                    'low':min_value,
                    'close':close_value
                })
        return index


def main():
    query = """
    select date,currency,bid from data_table
    where date(date) between '2022-01-13' and '2022-01-16'
    and currency like ('%USD%')
    """

    options = beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions(
        temp_location = 'gs://PROJECT/temp',
        project = 'PROJECT',
        runner = 'DataflowRunner',
        region = 'REGION',
        num_workers = 1,
        max_num_workers = 1,
        machine_type = 'n1-standard-1',
        save_main_session = True,
        staging_location = 'gs://PROJECT/stag'
    )
    with beam.Pipeline(options = options) as pipeline:
        inputs = (pipeline
                 | 'Read From BQ' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(query=query,use_standard_sql=True)
                 | 'Accumulate' >> beam.CombineGlobally(Currencies())
                 | 'Flat' >> beam.ParDo(lambda x: x.values())
                 | beam.io.Write(beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                     table = 'TABLE',
                     dataset = 'DATASET',
                     project = 'PROJECT',
                     schema = TABLE_SCHEMA))
                 )
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    main()
```

They way I execute this is from shell, using `python3 -m first_script` (is this the way I should run this batch jobs?).
What I'm missing or doing wrong? This is my first attemp to use Dataflow, so i'm probably making several mistakes in the book.

Comment: This should work in Dataflow just as it does in the other runners, and I'm not seeing any mistakes. Did the Dataflow job start up and complete successfully? Was there anything interesting in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

For whom it may help: I faced a similar problem but I already used the same code for a different flow that had a pubsub as input where it worked flawless  instead a file based input where it simply did not. After a lot of experimenting I found that in the options I changed the flag

```
options = PipelineOptions(streaming=True, ..
```

to

```
options = PipelineOptions(streaming=False,
```

as of course it is not a streaming source, it's a bounded source, a batch. After I set this flag to true I found my rows in the BigQuery table. After it had finished it even stopped the pipeline as it where a batch operation. Hope this helps